# Connect remote website to node.js and socket.io chat application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I have created a chat application using **node.js, socket.io and mongodb** and it works perfectly..

Now I am trying to implement a js code to connect any website that containing that code to my node.js chat application.

How I can do that? Is there any article or anything? I have been searching for 3 days and couldn't get an answer.

Comment: You need to talk about what you've tried so far that isn't working, not ask for a article.

Comment: Just make a request to your NodeJS app?

Comment: yes I want to make a request for my NodeJS app.. how please?

Comment: @GerbenHofman and the remove website is using apache any suggestions?

Comment: @EssamAhmed Please take a look at this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/